# Expansion of Summation

Tags: notation

I'm confused about expanding the multivariate summation notations.
It seems that following three equations are identical.
However, I do not understand how these summation become equivalent statements.

It will be helpful if any of you can provide comments or simple expansion with N = 2 in order to follow below statements.

1) $ \sum_{i\neq j}^{N} a_i a_j$

2) $ \sum_{} \sum_{i\lt j}^{N} a_i a_j$

3) $ \sum_{1\le i\lt j \le N}^{N} a_i a_j$

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In all three each of $i,j$ are somewhere in between $1$ and $N$ inclusive. The extra information mentioned at the bottom of the sum is meant as additional restrictions on $i,j$ for the desired sum. This makes it clear that (2) and (3) are the same, since if $i,j$ are in the range and not equal, one of them is less than the other. [So(2) explicitly says $i<j$ and (3) just inserts the range "from $1$ to $N$ onto that.]

Now for (1) it will be the same *provided* one interprets $i \neq j$ as meaning that $i,j$ are taken to range over the *subsets* of $\{1,2,...,N\}$ which have size 2. For any such subset, one of $i,j$ is less than the other, determining a unique term.

I have seen the notation of sum (1) used in cases where one is summing over *ordered pairs* $(i,j),$ which (for N>1) would double the value of that sum compared to the other two.